# Why does my foreach loop throw an index out of range error?

Tags: c#, razor, foreach

My foreach loop is throwing an index out of range error. I have a list of strings, and a foreach loop that is iterating through it. Here is a the code for my initialization of the list, and the foreach loop which is throwing the error.

```
const string modelString = "Acura,Audi,BMW,Buick,Cadillac,Chevrolet,Chrysler,Dodge,Ferrari,Ford,GM,GEM,GMC,Honda,Hummer,Hyundai,Infiniti,Isuzu,Jaguar,Jeep,Kia,Lamborghini,Land Rover,Lexus,Lincoln,Lotus,Mazda,Mercedes-Benz,Mercury,Mini,Mitsubishi,Nissan,Oldsmobile,Peugeot,Pontiac,Porsche,Regal,Saab,Saturn,Subaru,Suzuki,Toyota,Volkswagen,Volvo";
var splitString = modelString.Split(',');
var modelList = splitString.Where(str => !string.Equals(str, dynamicOwnershipChoiceQuestion.Brand, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
//dynamicOwnershipChoiceQuestion.Brand = "Audi"
for (var i = 6; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var ddcount = 1;
    //some html
    @foreach (var carModel in modelList){
        <option id="dd-@i-@ddCount">@carModel</option>
        ddCount++;
    }
}
```

The foreach loop goes through every item (Acura, BMW, Buick ... Volvo) and then keeps going for some reason. It doesn't stop.

To test the code, I created a for loop instead of a foreach loop. The changes are shown below:

```
var ddcount = 1; //changes after this
var modelCount = modelList.Count;
//some html
@for (var y = 0; y < modelCount; y++)
{
    <option id="dd-@i-@ddCount">@modelList[y]</option>
    ddCount++;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the same index out of range error after the loop has finished going through the loop. modelCount = 43. The loop runs 43 times, then y hits 43, the condition is set to false, and then the loop keeps going. ddcount gets to 44 (which makes sense because it starts at 1, and adds 43). After ddcount hits 44, the debugger goes back to the for loop and y gets set to 43. Then I hit next, and hovering over y < modelCount, both read 43. I then hit f10 (step over) and the error gets thrown.

I am unsure if I am initiating my list incorrectly. I saw somewhere that I had to do .add to new lists, but I figured that since I create my list with a Linq .ToList() it would work properly.

The inner error says it's null. Here is a picture of most of the details of the error.

[image]

Comment: Which line does the error actually occur on? I can't spot an issue with your for loop so I was wondering if it's occurring on the first line after the loop?

Comment: The error occurs on the line of the foreach loop. This line: foreach (var carModel in modelList) or in the for loop: for (var y = 0; y < modelCount; y++)

Comment: Are you sure, that your Code and your dll are in sync?

Comment: I'm unsure if my code and dll are in sync. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding. I will currently try saving, closing, shutting down Visual Studio, and restarting everything.

Comment: If you check the content's of modelList after you assign the Linq, what are it's values?  Does it terminate after the last value?  What's the count?

Comment: After this line of code: var modelList = splitString.Where(str => !string.Equals(str, dynamicOwnershipChoiceQuestion.Brand, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();

ModelList.Count = 43.
Values = (0 - 42) Acura, BMW, Buick, Cadillac, Chevrolet, Chrysler, Dodge, Ferrari, Ford, GM, GEM, GMC, Honda, Hummer, Hyundai, Infiniti, Isuzu, Jaguar, Jeep, Kia, Lamborghini, Land Rover, Lexus, Lincoln, Lotus, Mazda, Mercedes-Benz, Mercury, Mini, Mitsubishi, Nissan, Oldsmobile, Peugeot, Pontiac, Porsche, Regal, Saab, Saturn, Subaru, Suzuki, Toyota, Volkswagen, Volvo

Comment: Continued: After the last value, it says Raw View. Inside Raw View, Count is 43, and Capacity is 64.

Comment: Are you modifying the list in any way while it is being iterated-though?

Comment: If you remove the ddcount portions and only use `foreach (var carModel in modelList){}` does it still continue looping?

Comment: I am not modifying the list in any way while it is being iterated through.
I removed ddcount, as well as everything from the inside of the foreach loop. I still get the error.

Comment: I'm reaching here, but what if you try to assign a strong type to the carModel?  I'm not sure what type you need but perhaps @foreach(string carModel in modelList){}

Comment: I've dropped my code down to this:
    List<string> modelList = splitString.Where(str => !string.Equals(str, dynamicOwnershipChoiceQuestion.Brand, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
    for (var i = 6; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        //html
        @foreach (string carModel in modelList) {}
    }

The strongly typing doesn't help. Nice try though. I'm going to try manually adding each string to the list, instead of with a Linq query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101001/discussion-between-disciplemichael-and-millar248).

Comment: @Millar248 Has your problem been resolved? I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ddcount variable are correct in all references? For example, when you initialized the variable it was ddcount, lowercase C, but when you reference the variable later, it is ddCount, uppercase C. I would  correct that first.

```
const string modelString = "Acura,Audi,BMW,Buick,Cadillac,Chevrolet,Chrysler,Dodge,Ferrari,Ford,GM,GEM,GMC,Honda,Hummer,Hyundai,Infiniti,Isuzu,Jaguar,Jeep,Kia,Lamborghini,Land Rover,Lexus,Lincoln,Lotus,Mazda,Mercedes-Benz,Mercury,Mini,Mitsubishi,Nissan,Oldsmobile,Peugeot,Pontiac,Porsche,Regal,Saab,Saturn,Subaru,Suzuki,Toyota,Volkswagen,Volvo";
var splitString = modelString.Split(',');
var modelList = splitString.Where(str => !string.Equals(str, dynamicOwnershipChoiceQuestion.Brand, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
//dynamicOwnershipChoiceQuestion.Brand = "Audi"
for (var i = 6; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var ddcount = 1;
    //some html
    @foreach (var carModel in modelList){
        <option id="dd-@i-@ddcount">@carModel</option>
        ddcount++;
    }
}
```

Also, I would check how you write the htmls in //some html section, if it was pure html, then @foreach should not start with @.

Using you second section of code as example,

```
@{
    const string modelString = "Acura,Audi,BMW,Buick,Cadillac,Chevrolet,Chrysler,Dodge,Ferrari,Ford,GM,GEM,GMC,Honda,Hummer,Hyundai,Infiniti,Isuzu,Jaguar,Jeep,Kia,Lamborghini,Land Rover,Lexus,Lincoln,Lotus,Mazda,Mercedes-Benz,Mercury,Mini,Mitsubishi,Nissan,Oldsmobile,Peugeot,Pontiac,Porsche,Regal,Saab,Saturn,Subaru,Suzuki,Toyota,Volkswagen,Volvo";
    var splitString = modelString.Split(',');
    var modelList = splitString.Where(str => !string.Equals(str, "Audi", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
    //dynamicOwnershipChoiceQuestion.Brand = "Audi"

    for (var i = 6; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        var ddcount = 1; //changes after this
        var modelCount = modelList.Count;
        //some html
        <div>Car brands @i</div>
        for (var y = 0; y < modelCount; y++)
        {
            <option id="dd-@i-@ddcount">@modelList[y]</option>
            ddcount++;
        }
      }
}
```

And, lastly, I would assert that

```
dynamicOwnershipChoiceQuestion.Brand = "Audi"
```

Make sure, that it is not returning anything weird.

Hope this helps